# Leave selected channels out of discord.py loop

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have created a bot that will lock every channel when I type the command, however, I don't want it to lock the staff ones and the announcement ones.
Here is my code so far:

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['r'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def lockdown(ctx):
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for channel in guild.text_channels:
            channel = channel
            overwrite = channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
            overwrite.send_messages = False
            await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrite)
            await channel.send('Lockdown has started')
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exclude channels which you dont want to lock by name using a blocking statement. Like this:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['r'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def lockdown(ctx):
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for channel in guild.text_channels:
            if channel.name in ['dont_lock_ch_name_1', 'dont_lock_ch_name_2']:
                continue
            overwrite = channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
            overwrite.send_messages = False
            await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrite)
            await channel.send('Lockdown has started')
```